# Delta method for confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confidence-interval

I am calculating sensitivity and specificity from a model where the outcome is the measured value and the exposure is the true value. It is my understanding that I need to use delta method or bootstrapping to get the confidence intervals based on the equation (instead of just using `confint` in the equation)

Below is an example of the data I'm using and the model:

```
# create some fake data 
set.seed(1234)
neighb <- sample(1:2, 1846, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.6, 0.4))
neighb <- factor(neighb)
ind <- sample(1:2, 1846, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.65, 0.35))
ind <- factor(ind)
df <- cbind.data.frame(ind, neighb)

mq1 <- glm(neighb ~ ind, data=df, family='binomial')
coef_mq1 <- coef(mq1)
```

Then to calculate sensitivity:

```
m_seq1 <- (1) / (1+ (exp(-(coef_mq1[1]+1*(coef_mq1[2]))))) 
m_seq1
```

Then to calculate confidence intervals using deltamethod:

```
library(msm)
b0 <- coef_mq1[1]
b1 <- coef_mq1[2]
se <- deltamethod(~((1) / (1+ (exp(-(x1+1*(x2)))))) , c(b1,b0), vcov(mq1))
m_seq1 + 1.96*se
m_seq1 - 1.96*se
```

My question is. Is this as simple as just plopping in the equation into `deltamethod` or am I missing something here? Also, is there a reason to use bootstrap over this method?

Apologies if this question belongs elsewhere like cross validated or is a repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code appears to use the delta method to compute confidence intervals around the function that you defined in your second code block.

A convenient way to check this is to use the `marginaleffects` package:

```r
library(marginaleffects)

g <- function(model) {
    1 / (1 + (exp(-(coef(model)[1] + 1 * coef(model)[2]))))
}

hypotheses(mq1, FUN = g)
# 
#  Term Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %
#    b1    0.383      0.019 20.2   <0.001 0.346   0.42
# 
# Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, conf.low, conf.high
```

Which looks equivalent to what you had:

```r
library(msm)
coef_mq1 <- coef(mq1)
m_seq1 <- (1) / (1+ (exp(-(coef_mq1[1]+1*(coef_mq1[2]))))) 
b0 <- coef_mq1[1]
b1 <- coef_mq1[2]
se <- deltamethod(~ ((1) / (1 + (exp(-(x1 + 1 * (x2)))))), c(b1, b0), vcov(mq1))
m_seq1 + 1.96 * se
# (Intercept) 
#   0.4204386
m_seq1 - 1.96 * se
# (Intercept) 
#   0.3459737
``
```

Comment: This is a super handy package. I hadn't heard of it, thanks! It is way easier to just use this.